# Hive: Failed: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'ls' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'

Tags: hadoop, hive

Getting a ParseExeption failed/error when I log into Hive and try to do a list of files in my localhost directory using Cloudera Quickstart CDH 5.5. Haven't started anything (creating database, table and importing data) as of yet.

```
[cloudera@quickstart module2]$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.5.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
WARNING: Hive CLI is deprecated and migration to Beeline is recommended.
hive> **ls;**

**NoViableAltException(26@[])**

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1025)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:393)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1110)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1158)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1047)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1037)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:756)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'ls' EOF EOF

hive> 

***The EOF have less than and greater than brackets around them.***
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `!` for shell command or `dfs -` for hdfs commands from hive CIL

> `! <command>` Executes a shell command from the Hive shell.
>
> `dfs <command>` Executes a dfs command from the Hive shell.

```
  hive> !ls;
  hive> dfs -ls;
```

Comment: SAME RESULTShive> !ls;
ls;
NoViableAltException(26@[])
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'ls' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'
However; dfs -ls; works....

Comment: I only get the error when I use the list command for the localhost when I am in hive. For dfs I am good (see results below):hive> dfs -ls;
Found 11 items
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2017-01-19 20:39 .Trash
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2017-01-12 01:37 input
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2017-01-08 22:42 output
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2017-01-10 04:05 output2
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         62 2016-05-18 06:24 userInfo.csv
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2017-01-13 03:06 wordcount_out
hive>

Comment: seems you have tried `!ls; ls;`? it should be `!ls;`

Comment: Solved - Upgraded to CDH 5.8, no more issues.